# How to use SSL only on one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I want to make only one page request ssl certificate. I tried to use ssl_requirement gem  or bartt-ssl_requirement, so I tried:

In my pages_controller:

```
   ssl_required :admin
```

In my application controller:

```
   include ::SslRequirement
```

All my pages requires ssl, all are using https.

I tried to generate certificate only for admin page - entered in Common Name field site/admin, but by doing this my application doesn't working now.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I've accidentally down voted this question, please edit it so I can revert my change, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the SSL Enforcer gem by Tobias Matthies?
It's a pretty flexible and robust gem that will allow you to choose which paths need HTTPS and which don't...

Basically all you need to do is this:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => '/login'
```

Github page for more info: https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer

cheers